# Images for different devices

Tags: android, image, drawable

I have a problem with my app.

I had lower resolution images to load in smartphone, when I tested the app on tablet did not look good and increase the resolution of the images, but now in smartphone space memory fails and it blocked the app when I try to access a view to these images.

I wanted to know how I can fix this problem and I have in the project directory 'res' images that serve to both dispositives without problem.

I've heard that with suffixes drawable folders (drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, etc.) are used to take pictures of different resolutions and automatically each device take pictures from a directory or another, but I only use images in the drawable directory -mdpi.
In that case, what job directory for each type of device?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14215922/1405983. And also official document : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: This might help - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: You can store the images with different resolution in respective drawables folder like drawable-ldpi , mdpi, hdpi, xdpi and xxhdpi...

The image sizes will be.. let x be for mdpi
for hdpi = 1.5x; xhdpi = 2x; xxhdpi = 3x

Comment: ok thanks, but ... what directory I must use for each device? drawable-mdpi for smartphone and drawable-hdpi for tablet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272110/tablet-drawable-qualifier

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an app in which you want to support both phones and tablets gracefully

then you have to

- Explicitly declare in the manifest which screen sizes your application supports
- Provide different layouts for different screen sizes
- Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities

for more [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

You have to place different images in the respective drawable folders.

i.e

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```

for tablets you can specify different layout

i.e

```
layout-large
layout-xlarge

res/layout-sw600dp/   // For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/   // For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

with

```
drawable-large
drawable-xlarge
```